# Recursion - JS fails to return expected value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Somebody please help me find the mistake in my solution? Where could I possibly go wrong? I'm unable to find it.

Question : Write a recursive function called nestedEvenSum. Return the sum of all even numbers in an object which may contain nested objects.

My Incorrect Solution :

```js
function nestedEvenSum(obj) {
  // add whatever parameters you deem necessary - good luck!
  let sum = 0
  const helper = (obj) => {
    let firstElKey = Object.keys(obj || {}).find((key) => key)
    if (!Object.keys(obj || {}).length) return
    else if (typeof obj[firstElKey] === "object") {
      console.log("1st", obj[firstElKey])
      helper(obj[firstElKey])
    } else if (typeof obj[firstElKey] === "number" && obj[firstElKey] % 2 === 0) {
      console.log("2nd", obj, obj[firstElKey], firstElKey, sum)
      sum += obj[firstElKey]
      delete obj[firstElKey]
      firstElKey = Object.keys(obj || {}).find((key) => key)
      console.log("2ndAFTER", obj, obj[firstElKey], firstElKey, sum)
      helper(obj[firstElKey])
    } else {
      console.log("3rd", obj[firstElKey])
      delete obj[firstElKey]
      firstElKey = Object.keys(obj || {}).find((key) => key)
      helper(obj[firstElKey])
    }
  }
  helper(obj)
  return sum
}


var obj1 = {
  outer: 2,
  obj: {
    inner: 2,
    otherObj: {
      superInner: 2,
      notANumber: true,
      alsoNotANumber: "yup"
    }
  }
}

var obj2 = {
  a: 2,
  b: {
    b: 2,
    bb: {
      b: 3,
      bb: {
        b: 2
      }
    }
  },
  c: {
    c: {
      c: 2
    },
    cc: 'ball',
    ccc: 5
  },
  d: 1,
  e: {
    e: {
      e: 2
    },
    ee: 'car'
  }
};

console.log(nestedEvenSum(obj1)); // 6
console.log(nestedEvenSum(obj2)); // 10
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and ***expected output***

Comment: Your strategy here is the reason you can't see the issue(s), it's far more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Oops, someone voted my answer down can I know why?

Comment: So here's a couple of simplified objects that illustrate two different issues: `{a:{},b:2}` and `{a:{a:2},b:2}`. Use them to walk through the code mentally (or use a debugger to step through the code line by line) to see why your code handles them incorrectly. (There are more issues like this, but it should give you an idea of the sort of thing you should be looking for here.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete key/value pairs in your object unless you want your function to do this precisely. You don't want such a side effect to a "sum" function.

One way to do it is using a function parameter to store all the numbers during recursion, and simply adding even numbers afterwards.

Note: This solution also handles arrays like [{e: 10}, {b: 12}] and [10, 12] because `typeof [] === "object"` in JavaScript

```js
function getAllNumbersInObject(object, numbers = []) {
  Object.values(object).forEach(member => {
    switch (typeof member) {
      case "number": numbers.push(member);
      case "object": getAllNumbersInObject(member, numbers);
    }
  });
  return numbers;
}

function nestedEvenSum(object) {
  const addEven = (seed, next) => !(next % 2) ? seed + next : seed;
  return getAllNumbersInObject(object).reduce(addEven, 0);
}

var obj1 = {
  outer: 2,
  obj: {
    inner: 2,
    otherObj: {
      superInner: 2,
      notANumber: true,
      alsoNotANumber: "yup"
    }
  }
}

var obj2 = {
  a: 2,
  b: {b: 2, bb: {b: 3, bb: {b: 2}}},
  c: {c: {c: 2}, cc: 'ball', ccc: 5},
  d: 1,
  e: {e: {e: 2}, ee: 'car'}
};

console.log(nestedEvenSum(obj1));
console.log(nestedEvenSum(obj2));
```

Edited after Scott's comment

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I do have a question.  Why the scan for `innerMember`?  If the `member` is an Object, can't you just recur on it directly?  Also I think `flatMap` would beat the combination of `forEach` and an accumulator.  That is, something like `const extractNumbers = (o) => Object .values (o) .flatMap ((v) => typeof v === "number" ? [v] : typeof v === "object" ? extractNumbers (v) : [])`.

Comment: Also not the downvoter, but the question is "What's wrong with my code?", not "How do I solve this?"

Comment: correct @ouroborus , I've a much better "easy to implement" solution but I'm only asking for the mistake in my approach, not a new approach for this problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Indeed flatMap does the job really well, thanks for sharing. I'm not used to it because I think it is lacking browser support, am I right?

Comment: @KartikSaini I think your mistake is your approach for this problem

Comment: @Thomas: I think you're behind the times.  https://caniuse.com/?search=flatmap

Comment: @ouroborus , My approach pseudocode :-
* if the first value of the key of the object is an object, then recurse that first value of the key of the object.
* if the first  value of the key of the object is an even number, then add the number to the sum variable, delete the key value pair of the same, & then recurse the next first value of the key of the object (after deletion).
* If it is not a even number, then delete the key value pair of the same, & then recurse the next first value of the key of the object (after deletion).

Comment: @ourobirus * if the object is empty (after deleting all the key value pairs), then do nothing. Now, I don't think there's any mistake in my approach. Please don't make my approach my mistake if you can't find the mistake in my approach though.

Comment: @KartikSaini Deleting the key/value pair just to run a calculation on the object is a bad practice. What if you need the object again after? You would have to make a shallow copy just to run your code. This is some serious side effect, and not really a user-friendly function. Anyway, thank you for the -1 (I gave you +1 in return)

Comment: @KartikSaini You've heard of obfuscation? Bad practices tend to do the same thing. It's one of the reasons they're considered bad practices. Related, when the answer to "What's wrong?" is "Everything", it's hard to provide any kind of focused answer.